# How to Assign a Datasource to a Checkboxlist in an ITemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I'm trying to assign a Datasource to a Checkboxlist inside template for my DetailsView control.

```
private class membershipChkLst : ITemplate
{
    private CheckBoxList chk_lst_Members;

    public membershipChkLst()
    {
        chk_lst_Members = new CheckBoxList();
    }

    public object AssignDataSource
    {
        get { return this.chk_lst_Members.DataSource; }

        set { this.chk_lst_Members.DataSource = value; }
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        if (container != null)
        {
            container.Controls.Add(chk_lst_Members);
        }
    }
}
```

Is the syntax correct or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't call a property `AssignDataSource` as that implies more of a method name.

Comment: Why don't you pass the datasource as argument ?

Comment: @R0MANARMY - Ahhh... I'm still working on my approach since this my first try on it. XD
@V4Vendetta - That would be easier... I'm thinking too much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
public membershipChkLst(DataTable dt)
{
   chklst  = new CheckBoxList();
   chklst.ID = "chklstid";
   chklst.DataSource = dt;
   chklst.DataBind();
}
```

Pass in your required datasource (i added DataTable just to show) and this would help achieve what you want.

Comment: I see... This would also save a line to use DataBind once the Template's been instantiated...

Comment: I haven't been able to test run it yet. I'm working on this other project using ASP.NET MVC 2. Sorry, I'll update you once it works and I'll flag your post as an answer. =)